# Compute new pandas column (mean of other columns), only if NaN less than threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like a common situation, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere!  I have a number of survey scale items that I am trying to combine into a single score, but I only want to do so if there is not too much missing data. So far, I have:

```
    df['SCORE']=df.ix['Q1':'Q10'].mean(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

But I'd like `skipna=True` only when there are less than 3 items missing, else `skipna=False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `.apply` a custom function. Didn't test this code, but you get the gist:

```
import numpy as np

def mean_if_no_missings(x, no_missings=3):
    if np.isnan(x).sum() < no_missings:
        return np.mean(x)
    else:
        return np.NaN

df['SCORE']=df.ix['Q1':'Q10'].apply(conditional_mean, axis=1)
```